# List liked post in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Suppose

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(...)
    image = models.ImageField(...)
```

```
class PostLike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForiegnKey(User,...)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,...)
```

```
class PostSave(models.Model):
    user = models.ForiegnKey(User,...)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,...)
```

How do i list all the liked post in serializers with fields ["content","image","liked","saved"] ?
Here liked will be true for all as the list is coming from liked posts.
And saved will be true if request.user and post_id in PostSave.

view

```
def getLikedPost(request):
    obj = # Get all the liked post
    serializer = CustomSerializer(obj.,many=True)
    result = JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Help me in completing view and serializer

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `Post.objects.filter(postlike__user=request.user)`.

Comment: How do i reduce sql queries as number of query will increase with no of posts. What about field "saved" ?

Comment: all the `Post` objects that are liked by the user are fetched in *one* query, and the `request.user` in another, so the view will only make two queries.

Comment: Read question again